# Can I invocate a route in Fuse ESB and wait for a reply?

Tags: synchronous, fuseesb

Can I invocate a route in Fuse ESB from my application (maybe by using Exchange Send) and then have my application class wait for and receive a reply from Fuse ESB, after the route has done its job?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the request/reply EIP pattern: http://camel.apache.org/request-reply.html

You can send a message to Camel from Java code using the ProducerTemplate API: http://camel.apache.org/producertemplate.html

And it has methods that support the request/reply pattern, which are methods typically named with request.

When you do this, then the producer template will wait for the reply message automatic.